# Комментарии в CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать добавление и просмотр комментариев в CakePHP 2?

Answer (score 2):

Откровенно говоря, это всё отражено в документации. Стоит почитать, всё очень подробно описано. Но отвечу скорее для себя, чтобы не забыть CakePHP. Код проверен, рабочий. Вы уж сами, надеюсь, разберётесь как применить его для своих нужд.

В основном генерировал с помощью `cake bake`. Простейшие модели: Статьи имеют много комментариев (*Articles -> hasMany -> Comments*), а Комментарий принадлежит статье (*Comment -> belongsTo -> Article*).

В БД создаю две таблицы:

```sql
CREATE TABLE articles (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  created datetime ,
  modified datetime ,
  title varchar(127) ,
  description text ,
  comment_count integer
);


CREATE TABLE comments (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  article_id integer,
  created datetime ,
  modified datetime ,
  title varchar(127) ,
  text text 
);
```

Модели:

**Model/Article.php**

```php
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Article extends AppModel {

    public $displayField = 'title';

    public $validate = array(
        'title' => array(
            'notBlank' => array(
                'rule' => array('notBlank'),
            ),
        ),
        'description' => array(
            'notBlank' => array(
                'rule' => array('notBlank'),
            ),
        ),
    );

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Comment' => array(
            'className' => 'Comment',
            'foreignKey' => 'article_id',
            'dependent' => false,
        )
    );

}
?>
```

**Model/Comment.php**

```php
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Comment extends AppModel {

    public $displayField = 'title';

    public $validate = array(
        'title' => array(
            'notBlank' => array(
                'rule' => array('notBlank'),
            ),
        ),
    );

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Article' => array(
            'className' => 'Article',
            'foreignKey' => 'article_id'
        )
    );
}
?>
```

Контроллер **Controller/CommentsController.php**:

```php
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class CommentsController extends AppController {

    public $components = array('Paginator', 'Session');

    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Comment->create();
            if ($this->Comment->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Комментарий добавлен');
                return $this->redirect($this->referer());
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The comment could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $articles = $this->Comment->Article->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('articles'));
    }

    public function edit($id = null) {
        if (!$this->Comment->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid comment'));
        }
        if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
            if ($this->Comment->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The comment has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The comment could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        } else {
            $options = array('conditions' => array('Comment.' . $this->Comment->primaryKey => $id));
            $this->request->data = $this->Comment->find('first', $options);
        }
        $articles = $this->Comment->Article->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('articles'));
    }

    public function delete($id = null) {
        $this->Comment->id = $id;
        if (!$this->Comment->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid comment'));
        }
        $this->request->allowMethod('post', 'delete');
        if ($this->Comment->delete()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The comment has been deleted.'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The comment could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
        }
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
}
?>
```

Вид **View/Articles/view.ctp**:

```php
<div>
    <h2><?php echo h($article['Article']['title']); ?></h2>
    <hr/><br/>
    <p>
        <?php echo h($article['Article']['description']); ?>
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('Comment', ['action' => 'add']); ?>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Оставить комментарий</legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('article_id', ['type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $article['Article']['id']]);
            echo $this->Form->input('title');
            echo $this->Form->input('text');
        ?>
        </fieldset>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end('Отправить'); ?>

    <hr/>
    <h3>Комментарии</h3>
    <?php if (!empty($article['Comment'])): ?>
    <table cellpadding = "0" cellspacing = "0">
    <tr>
        <th>Заголовок</th>
        <th>Текст</th>
        <th>Создан</th>
        <th>Изменён</th>
        <th class="actions">Действия</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($article['Comment'] as $comment): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $comment['title']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $comment['text']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $comment['created']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $comment['modified']; ?></td>
            <td class="actions">
                <?php echo $this->Html->link("Изменить", ['controller' => 'comments', 'action' => 'edit', $comment['id']]); ?>
                <?php echo $this->Form->postLink("Удалить", ['controller' => 'comments', 'action' => 'delete', $comment['id']], [], __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $comment['id'])); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Комментарии в коде? Комментарии пользователей к статье на сайте?
В коде - стандартно, //комментарий 1 или /* комментарий 2 */
К статье - http://habrahabr.ru/post/22343/

Comment: Комментарии к статье. Я делал, как указано в ссылке, что вы указали, но при отправке комментария ничего не происходит.